# Custom fieldtype plugin

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

Any thoughts or tips on debugging a custom fieldtype plugin not showing up in `Settings > Plugins`?

Code base up at http://cl.ly/2E0m3Y2Z2R00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like there was a permission error on the folder for this plugin. This was due to pasting in a boilerplate template from pluginfactory.io

To resolve updated permission of folder and containing files and plugin was visible in back-end

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you figured this out yet but just took a quick look. It's showing up for me in the dashboard but getting a fatal error on line 45 just after installing it.

Looks like you have `MudDate::log`, probably should be `MudDatePlugin::log` (need the full plugin name in this instance I think, because Craft hasn't fully initialized your plugin yet?).